# The meaning of "pro"

Tags: meaning

I have a question about the word *pro*. Some software apps are called *pro versions*. What does it really mean?

When I google the meaning of *pro*, it shows me the result *professional* and *prostitute*. Then why are they using the name *pro* for software apps?

Comment: *Pro* does not refer to prostitution in any dialect of English I'm familiar with, except specifically when referring to a prostitute as a kind of professional (in the *[the oldest profession](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40857)* as the saying goes). There are several meanings of *pro* and *pro-*, but this is not one that should confuse anyone in reference to software.

Comment: Whatever site is defining pro as "prostitute" is one you should avoid using as a reference. It's either a slang dictionary or a parody, and either way is more misleading than helpful.

Comment: Hit me up with that prostitute software! Acrobat for hos

Comment: If you are an English-language ***learner***, you might enjoy our sister-site for [ell.se]. That’s because our sister-site is a Q&A site **especially made for *learners***, in contrast to the current English Language and Usage site, which is instead “a Q&A site for **linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts”**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A “pro” version of some piece of software is often a fully featured version of that software. This is as compared to “home” or “free” editions of that software, which when they exist are simpler or have less functionality or are limited to one user or computer, or which even have a licence stating that they are not intended for use at commercial organizations. “Pro” versions are usually intended for commercial use.

Answer (score 2):

*Pro* is short for *professional*, which  generally implies remuneration, as opposed to *amateur* which does not.

But *professional* has come to also mean **expert** or advanced, as opposed to novice or newbie.  In other words, it does not necessarily mean someone who carries out an activity for remuneration.

(A prostitute is a professional (in the first sense, of receiving remuneration). But most professionals are not prostitutes.)